# scrapy regex cannot find long dash

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, scrapy

I'm using scrapy xpath + re to extract data from web pages. Characters are unicode (russian) and all strings to be extracted contain long dashes (python code '\u2014')
The problem is my regex cannot find a full string and splits it by long dash. It's really inconvenient for me.
Here is some examples I've already tried and it didn't work:

```
response.xpath('some xpath goes here').re(r'[\w\s\\u2014\.,]+')
response.xpath('some xpath goes here').re(r'[\w\s\\u2014\.,]+')
response.xpath('some xpath goes here').re(r'[\w\s\\x2014\.,]+')
response.xpath('some xpath goes here').re(r'[\w\s\\uFFFF\.,]+')
response.xpath('some xpath goes here').re(r'[\w\s\.,—]+')
response.xpath('some xpath goes here').re(r'[\w\s\u(\w){4}\.,]+')
response.xpath('some xpath goes here').re(r'[\w\s(\u(\d)){6}\.,]+')
```

Versions: Python 2.7, Scrapy 0.24.6

Answer (score 1):

Turn your patterns into unicode strings and do not escape `\`.

```
response.xpath('some xpath goes here').re(ur'[\w\s\u2014\.,]+')
```

Also I guess you might want to use [`re.UNICODE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag so `\w` and `\s` will match all Unicode word and whitespace characters. According to Scrapy documentation [`selector.re`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.re) doesn't support flags, but it can consume compiled regular expression, so yyou can do this:

```
import re
response.xpath('some xpath goes here').re(re.compile(ur'[\w\s\u2014\.,]+', re.UNICODE))
```